# bson error when iterating over pymongo cursor

Tags: mongodb, flask, pymongo

I'm doing a search from my Flask app to documents stored in Mongo. My goal is to return the results of the search to my app. My view looks like:

```
@app.route('/search', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search():
    form = SearchForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        search_results = db.openings.find({"$text": {"$search": search}})
        print([i for i in search_results])
        return redirect(url_for('search_results'))
    return render_template('search.html', title='Home', form=form)
```

If I just print `search_results` I get a cursor object. When I try to iterate over the object, like I'm doing in the code here, I get `bson.errors.InvalidDocument: cannot encode object: <function search at 0x10df4d510>, of type: <class 'function'>`. If I attempt without the brackets, I get another cursor object.

Ultimately, I'd like to pass the results to the `search_results` template, which looks like:

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% block content%}

<div class="container">

    {% for result in search_results %}
    <article class="media content-section">
      <div class="media-body">
        <div class="article-metadata">
          <h3><a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ result.title }}</a></h3>
          <small class="text-muted">{{ result.company }}</small>
        </div>
        <p class="article-content">{{ result.description|safe }}</p>
      </div>
    </article>
    {% endfor %}

</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

What's the correct way to pass the results?

Answer (score 1):

On this line:

```
search_results = db.openings.find({"$text": {"$search": search}})
```

You are passing the current function `search` to the find statement. I doubt this is your intention. What is it you are searching for?

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I updated it to be `search_results = list(db.openings.find({"$text": {"$search": form.search.data}}))` which seems to have it working. Now I'm trying to figure out how to pass the results to the template!

Answer (score 0):

i'm not really sure but can you change this line over here;

```
search_results = db.openings.find({"$text": {"$search": search}})
```

to

```
search_results = list(db.openings.find({"$text": {"$search": search}}))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but still get the same error